# FrameworkUtil.getBundle returns me NULL always

Tags: java, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am trying to install bundle using OSGi framework. Below is my code which tries to get the `bundleContext`.

In the below code, everytime this line `FrameworkUtil.getBundle` returns me `null`.

Below is my app code-

```
    public App() {

        String basePath = "C:\\Tool\\LocalStorage";

        final BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();

                 // install various bundles-

        final Bundle bundle = bundleContext.installBundle(localFilenameOfBundles);
        bundle.start();     

        }
```

When I debug the code, I found out that in the `getBundle method` of FrameworkUtil class-

```
public static Bundle getBundle(final Class< ? > classFromBundle) {
        // We use doPriv since the caller may not have permission
        // to call getClassLoader.
        Object cl = AccessController
                .doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
            public Object run() {
                return classFromBundle.getClassLoader();
            }
        });

        if (cl instanceof BundleReference) {
            return ((BundleReference) cl).getBundle();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

`cl is not an instance of BundleReference` and that's why it always returns me NULL. And when I inspected on `cl`, I found something like this-

`sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@69956995` and which I believe is not an instance of BundleReference? I need to have this `org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader`

Below is my pom.xml file-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.host.Stream</groupId>
        <artifactId>Stream-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../Build/superpom</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.host.personallization.eye</groupId>
    <artifactId>eye</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>eye</name>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>                         <!-- Configuration of the archiver -->
                    <archive>                       <!-- Manifest specific configuration -->
                        <manifest>                  <!-- Classpath is added to the manifest of the created jar file. -->
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>   <!-- Configures the classpath prefix. This configuration option is used to 
                                specify that all needed libraries are found under lib/ directory. -->
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix> <!-- Specifies the main class of the application -->
                            <mainClass>com.host.Stream.eye.eyeApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.host.raptor</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>ConfigWeb</artifactId>
                                    <type>war</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>buildsrc/StreamConf</outputDirectory>
                                    <includes>**</includes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/config/StreamConf</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>buildsrc/StreamConf</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <file>target/config/StreamConf/eyewiring.xml</file>
                    <regex>false</regex>
                    <replacements>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>dynamic_build_label_place_holder</token>
                            <value>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${buildNumber}</value>
                        </replacement>

                    </replacements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <id>assembly</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${buildNumber}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.host.Stream</groupId>
            <artifactId>Streamframework</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.host.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucirrus-db</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.host.Stream</groupId>
            <artifactId>Streamcore</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-osgi-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-osgi-extender</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-osgi-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Is there anything I am missing here? I guess the problem that I am facing is of OSGi class loading. Because I think- Every Bundle has its own Classloader, a DefaultClassLoader. But in my case that classloader is different, I am not sure how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class was not loaded by an OSGi bundle classloader. In fact it was loaded by `AppClassLoader`, which is the default classloader in the JVM that loads classes on the main application classpath -- i.e. the jars and directories listed with the `-classpath` command line variable.

Did you actually create an OSGi bundle? Did you launch an OSGi Framework and install your bundle into it? Because it looks like you're just running plain Java here.

Comment: What I am trying to do is- I am trying to install various bundle programatically from the above code. After I get the bundleContext, I can use this to install and start the various bundles that I wanted to do. So the above code that I have is a simple maven project and it's pom.xml file I have provided above. How can I launch an OSGi framework into that? I edited my app code to show how I am installing and starting the bundles.

Comment: You can launch an OSGi framework using the `org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory` API. I wrote a comprehensive blog post about this 2 years ago: http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html

Comment: Thanks Neil for the link.. When I started using that, I got `NoSuchElementException`. I have opened a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244334/java-util-nosuchelementexception-while-starting-an-osgi-framework-programaticall) for that. Any help will be appreciated on that.

Comment: That exception means you didn't put an OSGi Framework implementation (such as Felix or Equinox) on the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that there is another not as obvious case in which "FrameworkUtil.getBundle" will return null. If the class you supplied is an extra class exported by the framework system bundle itself (bundle(0)), those classes will return a null result.  The cause is exactly for the same reason that Neil Bartlett explained; those classes are not directly resolved from an OSGI bundle classloader.  Bundles that import classes supplied from the system bundle work perfectly well; it's just that FrameworkUtil won't let you know that those classes come from the system bundle.

The reason you might do this is that you want to get a resource from the bundle that the class comes from.