# org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle SampleModel

Tags: java, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am trying to launch an OSGi framework programatically. I am using Felix framework for this. Below is the code I have which will launch an OSGi container.

```
public GoldeneyeApp() {

    try {

        FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //TODO: add some config properties
        Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);
        framework.start();

        BundleContext bundleContext = framework.getBundleContext();

        modulesNameVersionHolder.put("SampleModel", "1.0.0");

        List<Bundle> installedBundles = new LinkedList<Bundle>();

        String basePath = "C:\\ClientTool\\LocalStorage";

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : modulesNameVersionHolder.entrySet()) {

            String version = entry.getValue();
            final String filename = name + Constants.DASH + version + Constants.DOTJAR;
            final String localFilename = Constants.FILE_PROTOCOL + basePath+ File.separatorChar + filename;

            installedBundles.add(bundleContext.installBundle(localFilename));
        }   

        for (Bundle bundle : installedBundles) {
            bundle.start(); // this line throws an exception as soon as I start SampleModel bundle
        }
    } catch (BundleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am trying to install and start a simple OSGi module (SampleModel jar) that I have created. As soon as I try to start that module, I always get the below exception-

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle SampleModel [6]: Unable to resolve 6.0: missing requirement [6.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=net.sf.cglib.core)(version>=2.1.3)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
    at com.host.stream.goldeneye.GoldeneyeApp.<init>(GoldeneyeApp.java:62)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1345)
    at com.host.jetstream.application.JetstreamApplication.getInstance(JetstreamApplication.java:71)
    at com.host.jetstream.application.JetstreamApplication.main(JetstreamApplication.java:94)
```

Below is my SampleModel pom.xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.host.Domain</groupId>
        <artifactId>DomainParent</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1-RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- POM Information about the Project -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.host.sample.model</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleModel</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <!-- Packing Type is bundle for OSGI Library Bundle -->
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build Configration -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Apache Felix Bundle Plugin - For Generation of Manifest after Compile phase -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <manifestLocation>src/main/resources/META-INF</manifestLocation>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>SampleModel</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.host.sample.model.samplemodel.activator.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Import-Package>*,
                            org.springframework.beans.factory;version="[3.0.5.RELEASE,4.0.0)",
                            org.springframework.beans.factory.config;version="[3.0.5.RELEASE,4.0.0)",
                            net.sf.cglib.core;version="[2.1.3,3.0.0)",
                            net.sf.cglib.proxy;version="[2.1.3,3.0.0)",
                            net.sf.cglib.reflect;version="[2.1.3,3.0.0)"
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Configuration of repositories for dependency resolution -->
    <repositories>
        <!-- Domain Bundles Repository -->
        <!-- This is needed to locate the Domain Parent project. Other repositories 
            come from the parent. -->
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>http://nxDomain/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>thirdparty</id>
            <url>http://nxDomain/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
            <releases>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using 'Import-Package: net.sf...' in your manifest but you haven't installed CGLIB(or Spring Framework) into the OSGI runtime yet. If Import-Package doesn't resolve every required package, your bundle won't start.

EDIT: I forgot I had this: https://gist.github.com/sheenobu/5935468 . If you get pax-url working, you can then start installing from arbitrary urls.

EDIT2: also clear your frameworks cache otherwise you end up installing packages multiple times. Or check if the package is already installed as a bundle and, if so, don't install it.

Comment: Thanks Sheena for the suggestion. Now it makes sense a lot. Firstly, How can I install CGLIB (Spring Framework) into the OSGI runtime with my below code above? Secondly, How can I clear the frameworks cache? What I am seeing currently is, When I ran my code for the first time, everything went fine but as soon as it came to bundle.start method, it was throwing the exception. But now If I am running again and again after my first start, it throws an exception  during framework.start method for the bundles which I am not using now.. Might be framework has cached some bundles and it is starting.

Comment: You see the line where you call `bundleContext.installBundle`? That's how you install CGLIB (and the other dependencies you need).

Comment: Incidentally since you've obviously got past the problem in your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244334/java-util-nosuchelementexception-while-starting-an-osgi-framework-programaticall), how about accepting the answer? It's just good manners. And don't forget to accept Sheena's answer to this question too.

Comment: @TechGeeky See my 'EDIT2', yes packages are cached between restarts of the framework. Once you run framework.start it will use the existing bundles in the framework cache from the last run.

Comment: Thanks Neil for the suggestion. Yes I have accepted it, I forgot to do that.. I always accept the answers.  But I am thinking what lines I need to write inside `bundleContext.insallBundle` method to install the bundles for CGLIB. Just write the full jar name over there?

Comment: You can yeah. Just bundleContext.installBundle("file:/...path_to_cglib.jar") or whatever  URL that will point to it.